# Generate a public / private key pair in Julia

Tags: encryption, julia, public-key-encryption

I am playing around with some encryption / blockchain ideas right now that require the use of a public / private key pair. I looked at some of the existing packages and could not find one. https://gitlab.com/braneproject/ECC.jl provides much of the desired functionality but lacks the ability to create a public key.

Any idea how I would go about doing this? In Python, I would use `from ecdsa import SigningKey` to get this functionality. I also looked at https://github.com/JuliaCrypto/OpenSSH.jl but it seems focused on documenter.

Answer (score 1):

The library you mention depends on OpenSSH being installed on your system, and if it is, you can do the following in the REPL.  Hit the ';' key and you can enter ssh-keygen at the prompt, as in:

```
shell> ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (users/yourname/.ssh/id_rsa):
```